# How to recognize functions start address and end address in binary of PowerPC?

Tags: disassembly, powerpc

Given a PowerPC binary file(ELF), we can disassembly it, but how to recoginze the functions as the IDA pro does? Is there an algorithm?

Comment: the elf doesn't contain the debug symbols

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use objdump? If the elf file contains the debug symbols, you can see the functions and the code, as for example:

```
#include <altivec.h>
```

## include

void print_vec_char(char *s, vector signed char _data){
    int i;

```
printf("%s\t:", s);
for (i = 0 ; i <= 15; i++)
    printf("%3d ", vec_extract(_data, i));
printf("\n");
}

void print_vec_long(char *s, vector signed long int _data){
int i;

printf("%s\t:", s);
for (i = 0 ; i <= 1; i++)
    printf("%ld ", vec_extract(_data, i));
printf("\n");
}

int main(){
vector signed long int output;
signed char x, y;
vector signed char _data;
const vector signed char bits = {120, 112, 104, 96, 88, 80, 72, 64, 56, 48, 40, 32, 24, 16, 8, 0};


// Initialize the vector _data with the same values
_data = vec_splat_s8(-1);

print_vec_char("_data", _data);
print_vec_char("bits", bits);

output = vec_vbpermq(_data, bits);
print_vec_long("output", output);

y = vec_extract(output, 0);
x = vec_extract(output, 1);

printf("First Half  = %x\n", y);
printf("Second Half = %x\n", x);

}
```

and the functions in the elf could be showed as:

```
 # objdump -D test | grep print_vec_long  -A 10


 0000000000000924 <print_vec_long>:

 924:   02 00 4c 3c     addis   r2,r12,2
 928:   dc 75 42 38     addi    r2,r2,30172
 92c:   a6 02 08 7c     mflr    r0
 930:   10 00 01 f8     std     r0,16(r1)
 934:   f8 ff e1 fb     std     r31,-8(r1)
 938:   61 ff 21 f8     stdu    r1,-160(r1)
 93c:   78 0b 3f 7c     mr      r31,r1
 940:   78 00 7f f8     std     r3,120(r31)
 944:   56 12 02 f0     xxswapd vs0,vs34
 948:   d0 ff 20 39     li      r9,-48
```

or

```
objdump -D test | grep print_vec_long  -A 10
0000000000000924 <print_vec_long>:
 924:   02 00 4c 3c     addis   r2,r12,2
 928:   dc 75 42 38     addi    r2,r2,30172
 92c:   a6 02 08 7c     mflr    r0
 930:   10 00 01 f8     std     r0,16(r1)
 934:   f8 ff e1 fb     std     r31,-8(r1)
 938:   61 ff 21 f8     stdu    r1,-160(r1)
 93c:   78 0b 3f 7c     mr      r31,r1
 940:   78 00 7f f8     std     r3,120(r31)
 944:   56 12 02 f0     xxswapd vs0,vs34
 948:   d0 ff 20 39     li      r9,-48
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you. But the elf doesn't contain the debug symbols

Answer (score 0):

Look for padding to alignment boundaries as candidates for the gaps between functions.

`mflr` (move from link register) is often found near the start of a function, if it's used at all.  (non-leaf function).

Compiler generate code often ends functions with a lot of reloading call-preserved registers from stack memory, and often has most of the saving early in a function.

Of course, the actual return points in a function might not be the last basic blocks; it's often useful to put the code for a rare condition in a block at the very end past the normal return that's branched to, and then jumps back after doing something.

---

A real example of compiler-generated code may be illustrative.  Compiled by gcc4.8.5 on the Godbolt compiler explorer for PowerPC (32-bit) with `-O3 -mregnames`

```
int ext();
int foo() { ext(); return 1; }

foo:
        mflr %r0              # save link-register value
        stwu %r1,-16(%r1)
        stw %r0,20(%r1)       # ... to memory
        bl ext
        lwz %r0,20(%r1)       # then restore it after a function call
        li %r3,1              # return 1
        addi %r1,%r1,16       # stack pointer adjustment
        mtlr %r0
        blr                   # ret
```

**Notice that `blr` (branch to link-register) is used as a `return` instruction**, like x86 `ret`, instead of simply doing a normal register-indirect jump to the return address in `%r0`.  (Presumably PowerPC handles `blr` specially, maybe with a return address predictor stack).  If the code you're analyzing uses does this, it makes finding the ends of functions much easier.  (But remember that tail-duplication optimizations can give a function multiple return paths, and `blr` won't always be the last instruction.)

**The `bl` target addresses will give you (most of) the function entry points.**  Have your disassembler put labels on all the `bl` targets: branch-and-link is basically a `call` instruction, so the target address is always a function.

Functions that end with a tail-call to another function won't use `blr` at the end.

If a function is only ever tail-called, there won't be any `bl` instructions that target it.  Or if it's only used with function pointers.

Regular branch/jump instructions that jump more than a few kiB are almost certainly jumping outside the current function to tail-call another function.  So you should look at jumps like that as likely candidates for function entry/exit points.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a try.

Comment: Is it possible to use pattern recognition algorithm?

Comment: @xiaokangyin: If you have a *huge* amount of code to deal with, you could try.  But tuning all the heuristics would be hard.  I think probably your best bet is looking for `bl` target addresses; that should find most of the internal functions, and can be done automatically.  That's too simple to call it pattern recognition.  If you have a library where functions are only called from outside the library, those entry points will have symbol table entries.